Upload file to Azure via File API
I have a problem with uploading files to Azure via File API. I'm trying to run first request which creates file in Azure and it fails saying that authorisation header is incorrect.
This is my string that shall be encrypted:
const stringToSign = `PUT\n\n\n${contentLength}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:${currentDate}\nx-ms-type:file\nx-ms-version:2020-10-02\n/${azureStorageAccount}/${shareName}/${directoryName}/${fileName}`;

These are headers that I'm passing within request:
const headers = {
    'x-ms-date': currentDate,
    'x-ms-version': '2020-10-02',
    'x-ms-type': 'file',
    'x-ms-content-length': contentLength,
    'Content-Type': 'application/binary',
    'Authorization': authorizationHeader
};

Think the issue with with string, where values are not on the right place between '\n', but tried various options - no luck. Has anyone faced the same issue or at least can suggest the right string and headers?

Refer this doc for Authorize with Shared Key

One thing I noticed is that you are passing the content length of the file in stringToSign. According to the documentation here, it should either be 0 or an empty string.
Please try this:
const stringToSign = `PUT\n\n\n0\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:${currentDate}\nx-ms-type:file\nx-ms-version:2020-10-02\n/${azureStorageAccount}/${shareName}/${directoryName}/${fileName}`;

or
const stringToSign = `PUT\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:${currentDate}\nx-ms-type:file\nx-ms-version:2020-10-02\n/${azureStorageAccount}/${shareName}/${directoryName}/${fileName}`;


Thanks for reply. I tried that as well. Still doesn't work.

I also noticed that you have not included content type header value in your stringToSign. Please include that as well.

Still doesn't work. Here is the string -
const stringToSign = PUT\n\n\n\n\napplication/binary\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:${currentDate}\nx-ms-type:file\nx-ms-version:2020-10-02\n/${azureStorageAccount}/${shareName}/${directoryName}/${fileName};
